# Rails -v says I'm running 3.0, but I need to run 2.1.1 to get this app installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to do:

rake db:migrate

to get this app from github installed on my mac, and I got this error:

```
Missing the Rails 2.1.1 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.1.1 rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.
```

how can I temporarily or for this app only run 2.1.1.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is best to use [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) if you use Mac OS X or Ubuntu.

simply create another gemset

```
rvm install 1.8.7    or whatever Ruby version
rvm 1.8.7
rvm gemset create rails2.1.1
rvm gemset use rails2.1.1
gem install -v 2.1.1 rails
rails -v
```

and now you will be using rails 2.1.1.  You can create other gemsets, and also use `rvm 1.8.7@rails238` to change to the Ruby with the gemset.  You can also install Ruby 1.9.2 like the first line above and create different gemsets as well.

Comment: when typing 'gem install -v 2.1.1' i got an error saying "error while executing gem, please specify at least one gem name e.g. gem build gemname)

Comment: You really shouldn't install Rvm unless you seriously need to use a different version of ruby.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're not using RVM, just do what the error message says. Execute `$ gem install -v=2.1.1 rails` then you're good to go.